# How to paginate database records without using datagrid or gridview in asp,net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have googled and seems not to find a perfect answer. Most people make use of a gridview. This is what i'm trying to achieve. I am developing a website. I have about 50 records in my database. I want to display 7 records per paga and then provide a next and back button. i dont want to make use of a gridview because that wont be okay. I want to proper pagination technique where each data will be displayed in a div. I dont known what is used for pagination is a site like this but i want to handle my pagination like this too. Will really appreciate your suggestions and codes. A demo would be really appreciated. Help a rooky please. Please note that i don't want to use tables. Want something like that of php

Comment: personally i like this as an answer to your question and use it in the majority of all my projects https://datatables.net/

Comment: I feel like making use of a div to disolay each records rather than a table format. I have done a similar work using php where i echo the div and wrote my code for pagination. Thanks anyways

Comment: do you mean, one div per database table row? and then put the information in a label or input object? and then repeat that through the page? If so, I can see how you would want to achieve this and you can create database pagination through offsetting. If you need any help on that let me know

Comment: I like your idea and that is what i'm trying to achieve. One div per database table row. Will really be grateful if you shed more light on your suggestion. A little demo or article to guide me through will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Repeater` control, and assign to it the data source.
After loading data you get the total count, and divide by 7 to get page count, then create each link that point to the same page with > .aspx?page=X .
On load you use the paging technique in your DB engine to get the proper page and assign to repeater as data source.

Answer (score 1):

Do yourself a favor and look into jQuery Datatables.  You can still use a gridview, listview, table, whatever and Datatables sits on top of it.  Handles paging, sorting, filtering, search automatically.  And on top of that it's free.

The learning curve isn't that steep either, you basically download the scripts, refer to them in your code, and then apply the jquery to your table/grid object.

https://datatables.net/

Answer (score 0):

Following on from the comments you would want to do something like this to get the data

```
SELECT *
FROM YOURTABLE
ORDER BY SOMECOLUMN
OFFSET x ROWS 
FETCH NEXT x ROWS ONLY 
-- x represents the number of rows you want to bring back 
-- I would recommend you keep that the same as each other
```

then you would want something in your query string

```
http://yoursite?Offset=10&Fetch=10
```

this would be whats passed back to your code behind.

Now depending on your level of competence with .Net you can get the query string in a few ways

```
var fetch = 0;
var offset = 0
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["Fetch"].ToString()))
{
         fetch = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Fetch"]);

}

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["Offset"].ToString()))
{
         offset = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Offset"]);

}
```

The pass these values into a stored procedure. I am going to assume you know how do this.

Once you have the data back from the stored procedure and have the details in a DataTable unless youre using EF.

Loop through the you can either use a `Repeater` control as suggested in an earlier answer.

then you can pass the details back to the screen and this is where things will get interesting as I cannot assume that your using MVC or WebForms.  So the rest of this journey you're on your own I'm afraid.